# google app engine redirection pages in website

Tags: python, google-app-engine, button

i want to go from one page to another in my website using a button.
my code for this is like the following:

```
 self.response.out.write('''<form
        action="/sign" method=post> <br><input type=submit value="go to lesson 2 ">
        </form>  
''') % self.redirect("/lesson1")
```

now i am in lesson one page and i want using this button to go to lesson1 page but i keep getting this error:
PyDev breakpoint
inconsistent dedent at line 53, column 2
Bad Indentation (7 spaces)

does any one know how to fix this?

thanks 
Amal

Comment: The error message tells you your indentation is bad.  I suggest you listen to it.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from bad indentation and an errant attempt at using `%`, `self.redirect(...)` is done for effect, not to get a string you can use to embed elsewhere. What you've got it more properly divided into a `get` handler (to emit the form) and a `post` handler to do the redirect.

An alternative is to do the redirect in the browser, using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I got the correct answer using html.

I have two pages inside my website in google app engine and they are:

lesson1.py
lesson2.py

to go from lesson one to lesson using a button i put this code inside lesson1.py:

```
    self.response.out.write('''<form action="/lesson2" method="get">                 
    <input type="submit" value="go to lesson2" />
    </form> ''')

    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)], debug=True)
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/lesson1', MainHandler)],debug = True)
```

then in lesson2.py where i want to go i put this code:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)], debug=True)
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/lesson2', MainHandler)],debug = True)
```

an important issue is the app.yaml file mine looks like this:

```
application: Sign-language version: 1 
runtime: python
api_version: 1 
handlers:
   - url: /lesson2 
     script: lesson2.py

   - url: /.*  
     script: lesson1.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Preferences->Pydev->Editor and uncheck replace tabs with spaces. Tabs can be 4 spaces despite popular opinion that it should be changed to 8 spaces.